# RStudio does not execute `system` commands from Rprofile.site

Tags: r, rstudio

Using Rstudio (Version 1.0.143) under Ubuntu (16.04), if I add `system("echo 'Hello world'")` to my `/usr/lib/R/etc/Rprofile.site` file, I have no Hello world message displayed in R studio at startup.
If I start R from the terminal I have the Hello world message.

It seems that R studio ignores the `system` commands from `Rprofile.site` (idem from the `.Rprofile` file in the home directory)

Is it possible to enable system commands executions or is there a good reason to avoid this behavior ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For short, RStudio doesn't source `Rprofile.site` file at all. (I use Ubuntu 17.04 and compile R-3.4.1 myself)

## test `Rprofile.site`

To simply the question, you can use `x=1` rather `system("echo 'Hello world'")` in the `Rprofile.site` file. Then you open RStudio:

```
> x
Error: object 'x' not found
```

That tells you whether RStudio ignores the `system()` commands in `Rprofile.site` or R studio ignores the entire `Rprofile.site` file.

## test `system()`

If you find that your RStudio source the`Rprofile.site` file instead. You can try `system("echo haha > x")` or `system2('echo', 'haha', stdout = T) -> x`.

That tells you whether RStudio ignores the `system()` commands or you can't see the message due to other reasons.

## what RStudio says

Finally, see https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200643758-Rprofile-site-

> We don't actually implement the code for sourcing Rprofile.site (R does)

by Ian Pylvainen, Support Engineer at RStudio, Inc.

Comment: In my configuration Rstudio seems to source everything from Rprofile.site but not the `system` commands. If I add `x=1` in this file the object is well available in Rstudio. `cat("Hello world")` prints also the message. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45119432/more-meaningfull-window-title-for-rstudio) where we hack RStudio window title to make it more informative using `Rprofile.site`.

Comment: That's very interesting. You may try what I add.

Comment: Clever idea ! Indeed the x file is created on the disc with `system("echo haha > x")`. So the system function is indeed executed but the output is not visible in the RStudio R console. I missed that because the system command I wanted to execute try to manipulate the RStudio window title but from within the Rprofile.site it is executed just before the RStudio windows is present ! But I found another way.

Comment: Congratulations on your success!

Comment: url link is broken?!