# Problems with Rprofile, dont load at startup

Tags: r, macos, rstudio, startup, profile

I have a R (4.2.2) and RStudio (2023.06.2) installed on a MacOS system, before I update Rstudio I have no problem, but with those version I don't how to load .Rprofile at startup RStudio.

The defaul working directory for RStudio is in

```
~/R
```

and my ~/.Rprofile is at home

```
file.path(Sys.getenv("HOME"), ".Rprofile")
[1] "/Users/abraham/.Rprofile"
```

this is my info

```
Sys.getenv()
__CF_USER_TEXT_ENCODING         0x1F5:0x0:0x0
__CFBundleIdentifier            com.rstudio.desktop
CLICOLOR_FORCE                  1
COMMAND_MODE                    unix2003
DISPLAY                         /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.cH1daYw8Ax/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
EDITOR                          vi
GIT_ASKPASS                     rpostback-askpass
HOME                            /Users/abraham
LANG                            en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE                        en_US.UTF-8
LN_S                            ln -s
LOGNAME                         abraham
MAKE                            make
MallocNanoZone                  0
MPLENGINE                       tkAgg
ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP    undefined
PAGER                           /usr/bin/less
PATH                            /usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/abraham/Applications/quarto/bin:/Library/TeX/texbin:/usr/texbin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin:/Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/postback
PYTHONIOENCODING                utf-8
R_ARCH                          
R_BROWSER                       /usr/bin/open
R_BZIPCMD                       /usr/bin/bzip2
R_CLI_HAS_HYPERLINK_IDE_HELP    true
R_CLI_HAS_HYPERLINK_IDE_RUN     true
R_CLI_HAS_HYPERLINK_IDE_VIGNETTE
                                true
R_DOC_DIR                       /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/doc
R_GZIPCMD                       /usr/bin/gzip
R_HISTSIZE                      100000
R_HOME                          /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources
R_INCLUDE_DIR                   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include
R_LIBS_SITE                     /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/site-library
R_LIBS_USER                     /Users/abraham/Library/R/x86_64/4.2/library
R_MAP_DATA_DIR                  /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/maps/mapdata/
R_MAP_DATA_DIR_WORLD            /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/library/maps/mapdata/
R_PAPERSIZE                     a4
R_PDFVIEWER                     /usr/bin/open
R_PLATFORM                      x86_64-apple-darwin17.0
R_PRINTCMD                      lpr
R_QPDF                          /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/bin/qpdf
R_RD4PDF                        times,inconsolata,hyper
R_RUNTIME                       
R_SESSION_TMPDIR                /var/folders/dr/fp6pbm696ng3x0gyshc73mkh0000gn/T//Rtmp3P736Z
R_SHARE_DIR                     /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/share
R_STRIP_SHARED_LIB              strip -x
R_STRIP_STATIC_LIB              strip -S
R_SYSTEM_ABI                    macos,gcc,gxx,gfortran,gfortran
R_TEXI2DVICMD                   /usr/local/bin/texi2dvi
R_UNZIPCMD                      /usr/bin/unzip
R_ZIPCMD                        /usr/bin/zip
RMARKDOWN_MATHJAX_PATH          /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/resources/mathjax-27
RS_LOG_LEVEL                    WARN
RS_RPOSTBACK_PATH               /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin/rpostback
RS_SHARED_SECRET                9a1ba4e4-d844-432b-bfb4-1ba3f0a3b568
RSTUDIO                         1
RSTUDIO_CLI_HYPERLINKS          true
RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_COLOR           256
RSTUDIO_CONSOLE_WIDTH           108
RSTUDIO_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH   /var/folders/dr/fp6pbm696ng3x0gyshc73mkh0000gn/T/rstudio-fallback-library-path-492639873
RSTUDIO_PANDOC                  /Applications/RStudio.app/Contents/Resources/app/quarto/bin/tools
RSTUDIO_PROGRAM_MODE            desktop
RSTUDIO_SESSION_PID             1253
RSTUDIO_SESSION_PORT            31829
RSTUDIO_USER_IDENTITY           abraham
RSTUDIO_WINUTILS                bin/winutils
SED                             /usr/bin/sed
SHELL                           /bin/zsh
SSH_ASKPASS                     rpostback-askpass
SSH_AUTH_SOCK                   /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.3cVu9EHJfc/Listeners
TAR                             /usr/bin/tar
TERM                            xterm-256color
TMPDIR                          /var/folders/dr/fp6pbm696ng3x0gyshc73mkh0000gn/T/
USER                            abraham
XPC_FLAGS                       0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME                application.com.rstudio.desktop.42825593.42825598
```

This is my .Rprofile, I use some bioinformatics programs like blast that I use in R, so I add the bin folder to load those programs.

now to edit with usethis::edit_r_profile()

```
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "/usr/local/gentools/blast-2.2.29+/bin/", sep= .Platform$path.sep))

Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "/usr/bin/", sep= .Platform$path.sep))
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "/bin/", sep= .Platform$path.sep))
```

When the startup doesn't work, I just simply use

```
source("~/.Rprofile")
```

but it doesn't work when a startup RStudio again.

if I use

```
Sys.getenv("R_HOME")
```

This what I get

```
[1] "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources"
```

but if I check in shell, and locate the R configurations files are located in:

```
ls -l /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/etc/
total 56
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin  8475 Oct 31  2022 Makeconf
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin  2047 Oct 31  2022 Renviron
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   209 Oct 31  2022 javaconf
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin   831 Oct 31  2022 ldpaths
-rw-rw-r--  1 root  admin  1098 Oct 31  2022 repositories
```

in RHOME I got nothing

```
Sys.getenv("RHOME")
[1] ""
```

How to permanently set .Rprofile at startup ?

Thanks !!!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45185979/6574038

Comment: Can you do `find ~ -iname .Rprofile` or even `find / -iname .Rprofile` to look up if there are multiple `.Rprofile`s? If there is one in a project that you open, RStudio might use that and ignore `~/.Rprofile`.

Comment: BTW, better add directories to your PATH directly, on linux I modify  `~/.bashrc`, on macos I think it's called `~/.zshrc` or `~/.bash_profile` or the like. Add lines such as `export PATH="/foo/bar:$PATH"`, where `/foo/bar` is the new directory to add. Log out and in then or restart machine.

Comment: PS: In the terminal use e.g. `nano ~/.bashrc` to edit

Comment: I have no problems with zsh, I define the path in .zshrc just like: export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/gentools/blast-2.2.29+/bin  and its fine to run it in zsh !!!

Comment: Apparently this means that it now works and your problem is solved. Good luck!

Comment: no, the problem is with R, I use blast to create a package that call all the script within that program !!

Comment: @jay.sf Unless RStudio is launched *via zsh*, it doesn’t inherit the environment variables set at zsh startup. It’s a fundamental problem of macOS that there is no good way of setting system-wide environment variables (this used to be possible via launchd configuration, but it no longer works in the last several versions of macOS). — OP’s configuration should probably go into `~/.Renviron` instead of `~/.Rprofile` but that’s not explaining why `~/.Rprofile` isn’r being sourced.

Comment: @abraham I suggest that you add a message to your `~/.Rprofile` file to make diagnosing easier: e.g. something like `message(".Rprofile was read")`. — Next, inside R make sure that `Sys.getenv("R_PROFILE_USER")` is unset; if it isn’t, that is the reason why `~/.Rprofile` isn’t being sourced at startup. — `RHOME` is not a variable known to R, so it’s expected to be empty. `R_HOME` looks correct, but should not be relevant to your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I just add R_ENVIRON_USER="~/.Renviron"
R_PROFILE_USER="~/.Rprofile" to .Renviron file and then add the next lines in .Rprofile file: Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "/usr/local/gentools/blast-2.2.29+/bin/", sep= .Platform$path.sep))

Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "/usr/bin/", sep= .Platform$path.sep))
Sys.setenv(PATH = paste(Sys.getenv("PATH"), "/bin/", sep= .Platform$path.sep))

message("Welcome to my .Rprofile")    it print the message, but do not load the external programs, and I have to use sourse("~/.Rprofile"). Any advise, thanks

Comment: In one of my MacOS I have my R_LIB_USER in ~/Library/R/x86_64/4.1/library it works well; and the machines that I have problems the Library is located in: /Users/MyUser/Library/R/x86_64/4.2/library . If I check in / path in the machine with the problem, I found an other Library  folder in: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.2/Resources/  with all the files: COPYING, Rscript, doc, include,  man1,   tests, Info.plist, SVN-REVISION, etc, lib, modules, R,   bin,   fontconfig, library,   share. Just few day ago I have installed the new macOS  somona 14.0, that could be the problem ? thanks